# Android Phone is not recognized on Ubuntu/Windows via USB

Tags: android, debugging, usb

I am using Samsung Galaxy 3. I have turned on the debug option and have connected the phone via usb to ubuntu/windows but the phone is simply not recognized.

It was working perfectly fine i.e. recognized on ubuntu for me to work with Eclipse, until I decided to reboot the phone with usb still connected to the computer.

I have tried rebooting the phone multiple times and everytime, when I plug in the usb, it simply charges and no notification of usb connection ever shows up. What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Comment: i am using android 2.1 on Samsung Galaxy 3

Comment: Did you read http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html and did you follow the instructions there? If so, what do you see if you execute "adb devices"?

Comment: I agree, the Samsung Galaxy series phones are a pain when it comes to debugging. I haven't been able to solve these problems myself, but here are two things you can try - If the phone is not showing the "USB debugging on" warning even after you've checked the option, then simply restart it with USB connected. However, if it is showing that warning, the only thing that works for me is Factory Data Reset. Also, make sure that you never eject your phone when you disconnect USB - that somehow messes up the whole USB debugging thing.

Comment: If you do find a way to get USB debugging working without a factory reset, please do post here !

Answer (score 2):

try using a different USB cable.
I had a similar issue where my phone had previously connected just fine, but months later it wasn't recognized...

turns out the cable I was using was a "charging only" cable and did **not** transmit data.