# Using Xperia SO-03C Running Android for Debugging

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, usb, sony

I would like to use my Sony Ericsson Xperia SO-03C phone running Android 2.3.4 for debugging my app.  I have connected it to my Macbook Air via the USB port, and it seems Eclipse fails to recognize it (although I can charge the device).

I have already enabled "USB debugging" on the phone.  I have also tried "adb devices" and it does not show my phone.  I've also tried stopping and starting the server to no avail (adb kill-server/adb start-server).  I'm out of ideas on what to try next.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue indeed was the cable I was using.  It did not support data transmission.  This [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996406/%E2%80%A6) clued me in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the **device driver** for the phone?

Comment: My understanding is this only necessary for Windows.  Is it also for MacOSX?

Comment: I faced the same issue. It got resolved after I installed  drivers. But it was for windows.

Comment: Yeah, I was under the impression installing drivers was only necessary for Windows, not MacOSX.  Perhaps I am mistaken.  I'll research it a bit more.

Comment: Hmmm... I wondering if this could be it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996406/android-phone-is-not-recognized-on-ubuntu-windows-via-usb?rq=1